# Aggregated results show less items than doc_count?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch query which aggregates the result on a certain field, called `_aggregate`. Now I have this strange situation given this query:

```
  "size": 100,
  "aggregations": {
    "results": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "_aggregate",
        "size": 1000,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "bundled": {
          "top_hits": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "_weight": "asc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "_aggregate": "5713618784853"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

When I do this search, it returns 8 hits (like expected). However, when I take a look at the aggregated results, I see a doc_count of 8 (so far so good), but it only returns 3 hits.

Increasing the size of the `_aggregate` field does not have any effect.

Does anyone know how this is possible, or what can possibly cause this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the `top_hits` metric aggregation returns 3 hits by default. You can override this

```
  "aggregations": {
    "bundled": {
      "top_hits": {
        "size": 10,                   <--- add this
        "sort": [
          {
            "_weight": "asc"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Awesome this! I already suspected something like this, but I couldn't find anywhere. Thanks :-)